# If using a bootable Ubuntu USB drive, can I use the internal hard drive as a temporary download and staging area for software package updates?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, kubuntu, boot

I am new to Linux, so this is probably a basic problem...

My flash drive is only 4GB in size and that is not enough to hold kernel and other package updates, even if only temporary. I am actually using Kubuntu, but I don't think this would change the nature of the question...?

I would just like to be able to set my download directory to the internal drive to download the upgrades, then replace the old versions installed on the USB. Of course I have no use for keeping the older versions, so would I also have to manually remove those after upgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit here but...

Ubuntu downloads the packages it is installing to /var/cache/apt/archives

You could move the directory to your internal hard disk then create a link to that directory.

This *should* work.

A fairly new Ubuntu install is 2.7GB. I would move my data to the internal disk and the remaining 1GB or so should last you a reasonable length of time before running out of space. Ubuntu *should* clean up after itself, and get rid of the download when the package has been installed, so it will be additional programs that causes you problems, not updates.

Comment: I think this would be the best way to go about it. Assuming your external is mounted to `/media/external`, you would create a directory called 'archives' on the external, move all files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` to `/media/external/archives`.

Next, remove the archives directory with `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives` BE VERY CAREFUL when you type that command, `sudo rm` is very dangerous. To create the link, simply use `sudo ln -s /media/external/archives /var/cache/apt/archives`. To revert, do `sudo unlink /var/cache/apt/archives`, recreate the folder, and copy back the files.

Comment: I don't guess there's a GUI app out there that can help me do this, huh? I'm not confident with my syntax just yet.